# GraphCMS full Text Search Case In-sensitive

Tags: graphcms, hygraph

i recently started working with graphCMS and I am looking to implement the full text search functionality inside my nextjs app but i can't seem to find anything so I wanted to ask that currently does the graphCMS supports full text search or not? If it does how can I implement it.

I saw it does have a query for contains but i'm not sure that if is it going to work or not so you can suggest me anything about that?